# Why am I getting a “TypeError: this.state.users.map is not a function” for deployed production version of React application

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, google-cloud-firestore, axios

Built a web application using React to pull user information from a Firestore database. When running the application locally, it runs flawless and I can load the users information. After deploying it, I now receive a "TypeError: this.state.users.map is not a function" message and the page won't even load. Why would it work in work before deploying it and what would be the fix?

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import AllCoaches from '../components/search/AllCoaches';
import Banner from '../components/layout/banner';
import axios from 'axios';

// MUI Stuff
import Grid from '@material-ui/core/Grid';
import CircularProgress from '@material-ui/core/CircularProgress';


class coaches extends Component {
    state = {
        users: []
      }

  componentDidMount() {
    axios.get('/coaches')
        .then(res => {
            console.log(res.data)
            this.setState({
                users: res.data
            })
        })
        .catch(err => console.log(err));
  }

    render() {
    let coaches = this.state.users ? (
        this.state.users.map((user) => <AllCoaches user={user}/>)
    ) : ( <CircularProgress/> );
      return (
        <Grid container>
        <Banner/>
            {coaches}
        </Grid>
        );  
    }   
}


export default coaches
```

The output of the console.log(res.data) when running through localhost is:

`Array(5) 0: {userId: "name0", bio: info0,} 1: {userId: "name1", bio: info1,} 2: {userId: "name2", bio: info2,} 3: {userId: "name3", bio: info3,} 4: {userId: "name4", bio: info4,} 5: {userId: "name5", bio: info5,}length: 5 proto: Array(0)`

The output of the console.log(res.data) when deployed spits out what looks like my index.js file?

```
<!doctype html><html lang="en"><head><meta charset="utf-8"/><link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico"/>.....</body></html>
```

Comment: so you backend is not returning what you think it should be returning. So your route is not working.

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of issues here, I will point out the two most obvious ones:

The class name, 'coaches', needs to have the first letter capitalized in order to be a valid React component and to be rendered to the DOM.

State should be first defined as follows,

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
        users: [],
    };
}
```

Once you apply these fixes, your code should work as expected. If you run into anymore problems now or in the future, feel free to leave a comment and I will help you out!

Comment: I applied the mentioned fixes and still am receiving the same error: "TypeError: this.state.users.map is not a function"

Answer (score 0):

1.capitalized your component Name

2.to use state you must invoke super() method :

```
constructor(props) {
super(props);

this.state = {
    users: [],
   };
}
```

Comment: I applied the mentioned fixes and still am receiving the same error: "TypeError: this.state.users.map is not a function"

Comment: console.log(this.state.users) in render and share result

Comment: Result from the console.log(this.state.user) is Array(0) for the deployed version.
Result from the local host is (5) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]

Comment: you define users in your state but you  console.log(this.state.user) and get empty array take look to your user name in your state object